# Processing GET request in Django form logic

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-cms

I could really use some help here as I can't figure how to get this logic the way that I want.

I have a basic Django app and Django CMS as well.

On `localhost/find`, I have a Django form widget which displays a dropdown menu and a submit button.  If nothing is selected in the dropdown menu and the button is clicked, I want the URL to remain at `localhost/find` and have an error message displayed.  If the dropdown menu condition is satisfied, I want to display a page with the URL `localhost/fruit_info?selection=banana` and whose contents are dependent on what the user selected.  So, for example, if the user selects "banana," I'll display a page with information about bananas (stupid example, I know.  But I hope you get the idea, though).

Now, instead of what I want to happen, here is what happens:

The `localhost/find` page loads and the form is displayed.  Without selecting anything from the dropdown menu, I click the button and it takes me to `localhost/fruit_info?` which displays the exact form again.  Instead, I wanted it to remain on `localhost/find` and display error messages.

Next, if I select something and click the button, it takes me to `localhost/fruit_info?selection=banana` (which is good, meaning that the GET request is being sent), but instead of displaying the appropriate banana info page, it displays the form again.

So in addition to the error-displaying problem, another big question is how to create the logic that determine which fruit page is displayed.  Do I create one for each in the CMS admin?

Here is some relevant code.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    fruit = forms.ChoiceField(choices=..., required=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def find(request):
    form = SearchForm() # an unbound form
    return render(request, "find.html", {'form': form})


def fruit_info(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET) # a form bound to the GET data
    if form.is_valid(): # the dropdown menu has an item selected
        fruit_name = form.cleaned_data['fruit']

        # it's this logic here that I'm unsure about.  Do I return a separate page per fruit?
        if fruit_name == "banana":
            return render(request, "banana.html", {})
        if fruit_name == "kiwi":
            return render(request, "kiwi.html", {})
        ...

    else: # if nothing selected
        form = SearchForm() # an unbound form
        return render(request, "find.html", {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/',         include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^find/',          find),
    url(r'^fruit_info/',    fruit_info),
    url(r'^',               include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

**find.html**

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <div class="err">{{ form.errors  }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url "mysite.views.fruit_info" %}" method="GET"> #not sure if the action attribute is correct here
    {{ form.fruit }} 
    <button>Find</button>
</form>
```

Hopefully that wasn't too confusing.  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can totally relate to your same situation.

So basically you don't have to have 2 different functions (in views.py). 
Have one function to render and display the page. Something like

```
  if request.post and form.is_valid():
     '''
        search logic for the query 
     '''
     info = Fruitinfo...... (bannana)
     return render(request, "find.html", {'form': form})
  elif form.errors :
     return render(request, "find.html", {'form': form})
  else:
     form = SearchForm() 
     return render(request, "find.html", {'form': form})
```

This is how I usually handle the forms, and it's been working fine. I know the repetitive lines can be avoided, but to get a better understanding I have left it like that.